# DOM Elements created in JavaScript function disappear after function returned

Tags: javascript, spring, dom, dwr

I have a dropdown list with multiple selections allowed.  A user selects from the list and then clicks the submit button with an onclick=test() which calls a JS function.  I am using Jsp pages, and this is a Spring MVC framework project with DWR for remote service.

The data that's returned from the remote service - dwrService is handled by the callback function - handleAddSuccess.  Based on the item(s) selected, I need to populate one or more textareas.  From looking at Firebug, I see the textarea display and then being populated, but once the function, test() completes, the textarea disappears. I have been looking for answers everywhere, but no results.

```
function test() {
var careIDs = dwr.util.getValue("careIDs");
dwrService.getNewCares(careIDs, {
callback : handleAddSuccess,
errorHandler : handleAddError
});
}

function handleAddSuccess(data) {
    var aFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var divta1 = document.getElementById("divta1");
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var ta = document.createElement("textarea");
        ta.setAttribute("id", "definition"+i);
        ta.setAttribute("cols", "75");
        ta.setAttribute("rows", "75");
        divta1.appendChild(ta);
        aFragment.appendChild(divta1);
    }      
    document.body.appendChild(aFragment);

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       dwr.util.setValue("definition"+i, data[i].definition);
    }
alert(" end of handleAddSuccess " ) ;
}
```

I have also returned from the callback function, and the case is the same - I could see the textarea elements being setup in Firebug and populated with values, but once the function returned, the textarea element disappears.

Comment: On which browsers did you test your code? And don't forget to declare `i` locally using `var i`, otherwise `i` will leak into global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You don't `return false` from within `test()`, so the form gets submitted when the submit button is clicked and the page is reset to its initial state (depending on what the server does with the submitted form).

Comment: Marcel, I use FireFox, IE, & Chrome.  I changed the variables to local scope - tks!

Comment: Marcel, I use FFox, IE, & Chrome.  Changed the variables to local scope - tks! Just to be clear, are u saying that I should return true from test() in order for the form to get submitted? Actually, i do not wish to submit the whole form at this stage.  What i am doing is call JS fn which calls the DWR remote service on the server and have a refresh on the page for a portion of the page (sorry for the repetition).  I've other sections of the page and will submit the whole form altogether. Would it help if I submit my jsp page?

Comment: Marcel, just want to say that I did what you said to return true, from both test() first, and then from the callback fn.  Still the same, textarea display briefly.  -- Lin

Comment: @LinAhmad: No, you should just `return false` to prevent form submission. A return value of `true` will submit the form and exhibit the described behaviour.

Comment: I tried "return false" - no result.  Below is my modified script:function test() {
        careIDs = dwr.util.getValue("careIDs");
        alert("careIDs len = " + careIDs.length );

Comment: Tried "return false" - no result. Moved creation of textareas out of my callback fn and into test(). 
 function test() {
        careIDs = dwr.util.getValue("careIDs");
        form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        for (i = 0; i < careIDs.length; i++) {
            ta = document.createElement("textarea");
            ta.setAttribute("id", "definition"+i);
            ta.setAttribute("cols", "75");
            ta.setAttribute("rows", "5");
        }
        form.appendChild(ta);
    dwrService.getNewCares(careIDs,  {
    callback : handleAddSuccess
    });
  } .. appreciate yr help

Comment: The textareas and values in them are staying now.  I return false from test() and also for onclick="test()", I reworked that to be onclick="return test()"  Thanks!